# Problems with ParametricPlot3D options

Tags: plotting

I have the following code:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], t/4}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ImageSize -> Medium] /. 
Line[pts_] :> {Red, Arrowheads[{0, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0}], 
Arrow[Tube[BSplineCurve@pts, .003], {0, -.1}]} // First
```

[image]

It works as expected, but when I change Theme in `PlotTheme` option ( `Web` instead of `Detailed`) or if I remove `PlotTheme` option, then it stops working.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening, or what am I doing wrong?

In advance, I appreciate your appreciable suggestions or solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without  `... //First` it works for option `PlotTheme->"Web"`

```
    ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], t/4}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> {"Detailed", "Web"}[[-1]], 
  ImageSize -> Medium] /. 
 Line[pts_] :> {Red, Arrowheads[{0, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0}], 
   Arrow[Tube[BSplineCurve@pts, .003], {0, -.1}]}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ulrich!

Comment: You're welcome!